# How to determine the order of convergence of the Euler-Maruyama method?

Tags: finite-difference, convergence, numerics, stochastic, stochastic-ode

*This question [is originally posted in Quant.StackExchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/45466) but has been unanswered for some time so I ask in here.*

To make this simple let us consider the Geometric Brownian Motions (GBM).

**My questions:**

- **1. How can I show that the Euler-Maruyama Method is convergent using GBM?**
- **2. How can I determine the order of convergence?**

**Background and the Problems I am facing:**

According to Numerical Analysis theory **An SDE solver has order $p$ if the expected value of the error is of $p$th order in the time step size**

Now letting $S_t$ be a GBM with $S_0=1,$ $\mu=0.1$ and $\sigma=0.15$ then $E[S_{10}] =e$

When I run the solver $10,000$ times for different sizes $dt$, I would expect that the difference between my sample mean and true mean, $e$, will decrease as $dt$ gets smaller. However, when I run these simulations this is what I get:
[image]
**This does not indicate that the error converges to zero as $dt$ goes to zero?**

Why is that ..... Is this because of the randomness? I have actually tried for $1 \,000$, $10\,000$, and $20\,000$ simulations. In general, $10\,000$ simulations should be enough to remove much of variance.

Please suggest how I can determine/show the order of convergence.

If anyone is interested in the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

T = 10
mu = 0.1
sigma = 0.15
S0 = 1
ns = 10000


solution = S0*np.exp( mu*T ) 


dt_ = np.array([0.1,0.05,0.01,0.005])
err = np.zeros( len(dt_ )); 
for j in range ( len(dt_ )):
    dt = dt_[j]
    Sn = np.zeros( (ns) ) 
    for i in range(ns):
        N = int(round(T/dt))
        t = np.linspace(0, T, N)
        ex= np.linspace(0, T, N)
        W = np.random.standard_normal(size = N) 
        W = np.cumsum(W)*np.sqrt(dt) ### standard brownian motion ###
        X = (mu-0.5*sigma**2)*t + sigma*W 
        S = S0*np.exp(X) ### geometric brownian motion ###
        Sn[i]= S[-1]

    mn          = np.mean(Sn)
    print(mn)
    err[j]      = abs( mn - solution)

plt.clf();
plt.loglog(dt_,err, color ="black", label = "Error (abs)");plt.xlabel("dt",fontsize = 20); plt.ylabel("Error (abs)",fontsize = 20)
plt.loglog(dt_,err, 'o', color ="black" , label = "x")
plt.title("loglog-plot",fontsize = 30);
plt.loglog(dt_,0.05*dt_**0.5, linestyle = ":")
```

The code is mostly just copy-pasted from StackOverflow